# get sorted list of files from a directory

Tags: haskell

I want a sorted list of files from a directory. How do I apply the `sort` function to a list with `IO` monad?

```
import System.Directory 
import Data.List

sortedFiles :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
sortedFiles path = do
    files <- getDirectoryContents "."
    return sort files                   -- this does not work
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original problem is just lack of parentheses, as currently `return` is being applied to two arguments (`sort` and `files`), just fix that up:

```
sortedFiles path = do
    files <- getDirectoryContents "."
    return (sort files)
```

If you want you can `fmap` the sort function over the directory contents. It kind of has a nice, direct feel to it, basically lifting the sort function up into the IO monad:

```
sortedFiles path = sort `fmap` getDirectoryContents path
```

Comment: Thanks for the fmap example! I thought fmap applies to each single list item, but I can also fmap the whole `[FilePath]`.

Comment: Indeed, here the `fmap` is from the `IO` instance, not the `[]` (list) instance.

Answer (score 4):

The `return` function doesn't take two arguments. (There's an exception to this, but it's not important for beginners - it doesn't do anything like what you'd expect.) This is because `return` is a function, not syntax. All the standard syntax rules for functions apply to it. You want to pass return the result of `sort files`, but that's not what the syntax you're using says to do.

You want either `return (sort files)` or `return $ sort files`.

The two are exactly equivalent. The latter is slightly more idiomatic Haskell. Most people prefer using the `$` operator to using parentheses, when both are equivalently readable.

Answer (score 3):

Others already pointed to the lack of parens.

But here's a shorter and more readable version:

```
import System.Directory 
import Data.List
import Control.Applicative

sortedFiles :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
sortedFiles =  sort <$> getDirectoryContents
```

Comment: Could you briefly tell how/where `<$>` is defined?

Comment: It's defined in `Control.Applicative` and it's synonym for `fmap`.